# Не работает ссылка. Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Есть файл: *resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php*
В *web.php* на него нет route.

*email.blade.php* запускается по ссылке *../password/reset*.

Каким образом это происходит?

А если вставить строчку

```
Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@setNewPassword');
```

страница вообще перестает отображаться.

Как? Почему?

Comment: а в `web.php` нет `Auth::routes()`?

Comment: есть. Как это влияет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выяснения в комментарии, раз у вас прописан в роутах `Auth::routes()`, это означает, что у вас автоматически прописаны стандартные роуты для авторизации/регистрации. Как раз роут `/password/reset` обрабатывается там, попробуйте убрать запись `Auth::routes()` и проверить.

Comment: А я могу перебить своим роутом стандартный роут?

Comment: если не путаю, то после вызова `Auth::routes()`, пропишите свой роут, вроде должно работать

Comment: В том-то и дело перебивает, только почему-то после этого ложится страничка _localhost/login_. Выдает ошибку `Route [password.request] not defined. (View: C:\projects_laravel\red-market\resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)`

Comment: Так вы свой кастомный роут вписали, но не дали ему название `password.request`, напишите свой роут так: `Route::get('/password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@setNewPassword')->name('password.request');`